# undefined local variable or method `article_params' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

**articles_controller.rb**

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render new
    end

    private
      def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
      end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

'''

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #layout=false 
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/second'
  get 'articles/new'
  post 'articles/new'
  #get 'articles/show'
  #get 'articles/index'
  #get 'articles/new'
  resources :articles
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'welcome#index'
end'
```

'''

**show.html.erb**
You are copied content of routes.rb to show.html.erb

**index.html.erb**
'''

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

'''

**new.html.erb**

'''

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |form| %>
 <h1>new artical page</h1>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

'''

**schema.rb**

'''

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_11_30_073138) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

'''

**database.yml**

'''

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

'''

**yymmddttss_create_articles.rb**

'''

```
 class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

'''

**i don't know where im making mistake.
please when you reply it then make changes in above codes.**

Comment: Please post the full error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove one 'end' at the bottom of controller

```
 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render new
    end

    private
      def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
      end
end
```

Comment: private section doesn't need end @max

Answer (score 0):

You hare missing the `end` here

```
if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render new
# here
```

So the next line where you think it's closing the method it's actually closing that "if/else" block and your `article_params` method ends up INSIDE the `create` method

EDIT: also remove the last `end` after the `article_params` definition